# Organizing all additional plugins/extensions into main.js [VueJs]

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2

Is there any way where I can include all my additional extensions such as (bootstrap.css, vue-moment, vue-axios, bootstrap-vue and etc) into main.js and register it as a global component to be used by all of the other .vue files in my components page?

As I have many pages that might need to use axios and other extensions, I do not want to include this code in every .vue page.

```
 import axios from "axios"
```

I have tried including all of the imports into main.js and added

```
 Vue.use()
```

However some extensions like moment or axios or datetimepicker will still be required to be included in the component page for it to work properly. Else it will say that it is not defined.

For example.

Components folder - main.vue

```
 import axios from "axios"; <-- (I do not want to include this here)
 import moment from "moment"; <-- (I do not want to include this here)
```

Main.js

```
//I want all my extensions to be listed here and able to use throughout all of the components pages
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import moment from 'vue-moment'

Vue.use(axios, moment);  

new Vue({
   router,
   render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Thanks!

Comment: there are vue-axios and vue-moment that will work as u expect, i know this is not solution but work around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you can use the prototype of your Vue instance for JS libraries like `moment` or `axios`.

`main.js`:

```
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.prototype.$http = axios
```

`Login.vue`:

```
export default {
    mounted () {
        this.$http.get(...)
    }
}
```

---

BootstrapVue is providing a very good [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/) with explanations on how to register the components and import the styles.

`main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
```

`App.vue`:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
```

Comment: Yup, this is the answer that I could use.

Comment: -Deleted comment-

Answer (score 0):

This article explains it really well
https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/04/22/vue-js-libraries-plugins/

For me, I decided to go with this method.

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(VueAxios,axios);
```

filename.vue - this is how I will access it

`//By adding "this" in front, it seems to be working fine. 
    this.axios({...}}`